# Swift convert string with specific format to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I would like to convert these two strings to NSDate.

## 1.`"2015-10-19T15:27:48.173754Z"`

## 2.`"2015-10-19T15:27:31Z"`

I tried using this function for format #1:

```
static func prepareDate(dateString: String)-> NSDate
{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
    return date
}
```

But it always return nil. Can someone advice what is the problem?

Comment: The date format in your code doesn't match the first string at all. It will match the 2nd string if you properly quote the `T` in the format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote the `T` with ' marks

```
func prepareDate(dateString: String)-> NSDate?
{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
    return date
}
```

Its parsing as part of the date magic formatters.

`let test = "2015-10-19T15:27:31Z" -> "Oct 19, 2015, 4:27 PM"`

Comment: Thanks that is the solution!